# how to add two time variable in php

Tags: php, time

I want to add 2 time variable in php. I use below code but it returns a big number. how can I have a time like (15:20:00) at the end?

code :

```
    $time1="10:00:00";
    $time2="05:20:00";
    $sum = strtotime($time1)+strtotime($time2);
    echo date("H:i:s",$sum);
```

Expected result: `15:20:00`

Comment: $CBroe I did not get my answer with this link, if you think it's duplicate please answer my question with the information that you got with that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like :

```
    echo sum_the_time($time1, $time2); 

function sum_the_time($time1, $time2) {
  $times = array($time1, $time2);
  $seconds = 0;
  foreach ($times as $time)
  {
    list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':', $time);
    $seconds += $hour*3600;
    $seconds += $minute*60;
    $seconds += $second;
  }
  $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
  $seconds -= $hours*3600;
  $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
  $seconds -= $minutes*60;
  return "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
}
```

Comment: your code returns 08:51:44 too. I want the result to be 15:20:00. is that something wrong with my times?

Comment: @mj-y just edited my answer.

Comment: dont reinvent the wheel uses php date and time functions properly

Comment: What do you mean and why do I get a downvote? @Dagon

Answer (score 2):

Add to the end

```
$sum = strftime('%H:%M:%S', $sum);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: your code returns '08:51:44' , and it is not the real summation...